# Error: "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' ". when first time deploy project of asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I am new to asp.net and I create a small application in visual studio using mvc4. now I want to deploy my application on the IIS local server. for that I publish my application..there is no error in publishing the application.

but when I run on a local server that gives me error like "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' "...

I don't know how to solve this error...can anyone help me to solve this

here is my web.config file code

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-RedICMVC-20181218045419.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-RedICMVC-20181218045419;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="RedICMVCDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HP;initial catalog=RedICMVC;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

thank you in advance

this is my IIS server connection string 
[image: IIS Server Connection string]

and this connection string used in the application currently 
[image: My connection string]

After Change to Specify credentials it giving me error like "Keyword not supported: 'server'."

[image: I change this type my connection string]

this will give me error like this
[image: Keyword not support 'server']

Comment: You're using integrated security to connect to the db, its not using an account on the IIS server hence anonymous.

Comment: how to solve this.?

Comment: Either you need users to authenticate so it connects as them, or you set the pool user